# Changes in /etc/hosts are undone

Tags: macos

I have a computer on my local network for which I would like to use a nice alias, and therefore I put an entry in /etc/hosts. After a while this change is undone. The entry is gone from /etc/hosts. It happens repeatedly for several days now.

Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Can you describe the process you use to edit the hosts file?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a Cisco VPN client?

Check out [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/354902/etc-hosts-getting-reset-in-lion) on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

In this case you might need to catch the culprit process that is editing the file. Tools like [fseventer](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart) or just the command line tool `fs_usage` should be enough to see when the /private/etc/hosts file gets written or modified.

Many programs are known to edit that file destructively, but guessing which might be harder than simply tracking your instance down. Please edit this or answer yourself if you do find the culprit in your instance.